# Excel data grouping

Tags: excel

As you can see on the left, there are several lines with the same purpose (here the name, the first name, and the study of several students).
In order to have something readable, is there a simple way to group in a single column all lines with the same title ?

For example, I have 5 lines beginning with "Prénom", can I group them in a single column with "Prénom" as header and the list of all the lines below ?

One of the tools put in place was to create a database of all the students then to ask the database to make comparisons before re-sorting the table. But is there a simpler way to do this using Excel's native tools ?

I also tried to do it with the PivotTables but it just creates columns named "Name 1" "Name 2" "Name 3" etc instead of grouping them under the same name.

[Photo of the Excel page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bChCP.png)

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Select all table data.. then click the filter button at 'Projet' column, then choose sort. That shall do what you said.